# Android MenuProvider adding menu items out of order when resuming activity w/ fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-support-library, provider

Has anyone seen this?  Feels like a bug in the Android MenuProvider.

1. Activity A has menu items 1 & 2.
2. Fragment A in Activity A has menu items 3 & 4.  Menu items are in order: 1,2,3,4
3. startActivity Activity B from Activity A
4. close Activity B and resume Activity B
5. The action bar menu now has menu items in order: 3,4,1,2 instead of 1,2,3,4

Lifecycle version 2.6.2
Nav version 2.7.5
AppCompat 1.6.1

I haven't seen any related bug report on b.android.com or question here.

Comment: If you add a `LifecycleObserver` to both your activity and fragment, you'll see that the fragment does indeed reach `STARTED` before the Activity - that's [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127528777).

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake...starred it.  I also found a workaround but it's not the prettiest...when I call addMenuProvider in the fragment with "requireActivity()" as the lifecycleowner instead of using viewLifecycleOwner as the docs for menuProvider say to use.  Doesn't work well if the fragment has a nested viewpager though.

Comment: I take it back..doesn't work..ends up adding a lot of copies of the fragments menu..lol.
This bug seems to make menuprovider only usable if you don't add menu options from fragments?

Comment: Ahh..found my bug. In the Activity, I used the wrong version of addMenuProvider().

Don't use the one with a lifecycleowner and lifecycle state.  Just use the single arg addMenuProvider() in your Activity.  This probably needs a lint rule...

Comment: "only usable if you don't add menu options from fragments" - more like if you don't use the Activity lifecycle - fragments and nested fragments all actually get started in the right order (parent first, then child fragments, etc.) - that bug explains that there isn't the same nesting between activities and fragments (even though you'd think no fragment would ever be started before the containing activity is started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong version of addMenuProvider(). Don't use the one with a lifecycleowner and lifecycle state. Just use the single arg addMenuProvider() in your Activity.